# Bootstrap: Navbar isn't responsive: overlap / breakpoint at sm-sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, overlap

The navbar works fine on large desktops, but if the browser size is beetween about 781px and 1005 px the li tag links don't fit into the navbar and that causes a overlap or breaking into two "lines" (example "Kontakt"). You can see it on my screenshot of the navbar.

Screenshot: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140517/5ov7sr5v.png

I'm templating with Bootstrap and LESS on Joomla 3.3.

Here's some code.

HTML:

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <?php /* <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>"><?php echo $siteName; ?></a> */ ?>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</nav><!--/ .navbar navbar-default -->
```

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />` throws `<ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">`
and for the second level (dropdown): `<ul class="dropdown-menu nav-child unstyled small">`

JavaScript:

```
        // bootstrap dropdown menu
    $('.navbar .parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
    $('.navbar .dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
    $('.navbar .dropdown-toggle').append(' <b class="caret"></b>');
```

Template.less:

```
.navbar {
background-image:url(../images/menu_bg.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: @font-size-base;
border-radius:0;

ul {
    li {

        border-right:1px solid @navbar-default-border;

        &:hover {

        }

        a {

            &:first-child {

            }
            &:last-child {
                border-right:none;
            }
        }
    }
} //.ul
```

} //.navbar

I didn't change any size properties in variables.
@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-sm-min;
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);

How can I fix this problem? It's important, that the website is responsive.

Another problem is the toggle button. It appears and it works if I click on it but I can not click on it again to let the menu disappear.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the image is that you simply have too many nav items to fit the width of your page. Try using `@media` queries to target the padding on `.nav > li > a` so when you shrink the page it will reduce the `padding`

The `min` and `max` width are just default sizes. I've added a `min` because below `768px` Bootstraps collapse menu should kick in.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1224px)
                   and (min-device-width : 768px) {

    .nav {
        > li {
            > a {
                /* Default - padding: 10px 15px;*/
                padding: 10px 12px;
            }
        }
    }

}
```